# IFS-separated items in loop

Tags: bash

It is recommended to use IFS to loop through comma-separated list, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23561892/1083704). But, I see that

```
sentences="Hello World,Questions"
IFS=, sentences1=($sentences) # if we comment this line then loop is fixed
sentences2=$sentences
for sentence in ${sentences2[@]}; 
do
    for i in $(seq 1 2);
    do
            #This is fine - prints a new word every line
            #echo $sentence

            #This is fine - prints new number every line
            #echo $i

            echo $i $sentence
    done
done
```

produces

```
1 
2 Hello World
1
2 Question
```

Instead of

```
1 Hello World
2 Hello World
1 Question 
2 Question
```

desired. WASA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that the second line, `IFS=, sentences1=($sentences)`, sets IFS to "," permanently; this means that you get weird and unexpected parsing behavior throughout the rest of the script. Note that with something like `IFS=, read ...`, this wouldn't happen because the IFS assignment is treated as applying only to the `read` command; but in `IFS=, sentences1=($sentences)`, there's no real command, just assignments, so the assignments are treated as applying to the entire shell.

So, let's take a look at what happens in the rest of the script. `sentences2=$sentences` just copies `sentences` into `sentences2`, so `for sentence in ${sentences2[@]}` is a little weird. `sentences2` isn't an array (just a plain string), so the `[@]` bit doesn't do anything, but since IFS is still ",", it gets "word-split" into "Hello World" and "Questions" -- i.e. you get the right result, but for the wrong reason.

(Note: if it were an actual array, you'd want to have double-quotes around it, as in `for sentence in "${sentences2[@]}"` to prevent the elements from getting word-split.)

The next command, `for i in $(seq 1 2)`, is where the real trouble begins. `seq 1 2` prints "1[newline]2[newline]", the `$( )` construct trims the trailing newline, and then "1[newline]2" gets word-split -- but since there's no comma there, it's treated as one word (that happens to contain a newline). Thus, the inner loop runs just once, with `i` set to "1[newline]2".

The next line, `echo $i $sentence`, prints "1[newline]2" followed by a space, followed by the contents of `sentence`. On the first iteration, with `sentence` set to "Hello World", this prints:

```
1 
2 Hello World
```

...the newline in the middle makes this look like two things being printed, but it's really just one `echo` that happens to contain a newline.

So, two big recommendations: First, when you change IFS, change it back afterward. Second, always double-quote variable references to avoid unexpected word splitting (and wildcard expansion). Here's what I get for the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sentences="Hello World,Questions"

saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=, sentences1=($sentences)
IFS="$saveIFS"  # Set IFS back to normal!

for sentence in "${sentences1[@]}"; do  # Note double-quotes, and sentences1 is 
an actual array  
    for i in $(seq 1 2); do  # No double-quotes, we *want* seq's output to be spli
t
        echo "$i" "$sentence"  # Double-quotes for safety
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is the reason but irc://freenode/bash provides the solution

```
while IFS=, read -ra items; do
    for item in "${items[@]}"; do
        for i in {1..3}; do
            printf '%d %s\n' "$i" "$item"
        done
    done
done <<< "Hello World,Questions,Answers"
```

that prints properly.